# aws-ec2 java website hosting on amazon-ec2

Tags: java, xml

I am hosting a java website on amazon web service but I am getting a problem when. I deployed it on tomcat that is installed on amazon-server it gives me a `"status 404-not found"` error. How would I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using spring boot application, if yes then you need to extend SpringBootServletInitializer into your application class. As internal springboot use embed tomcat server.